Check which of two enums a variable belongs to
I have 2 enums and a variable.
The variable contains an array of objects.
One of the props of which contains the value of one of the enums.
I need to check which of the enums owns the value of the object type.
I have something like that:
enum Animal {
  CAT = 'cat',
  DOG = 'dog',
}

enum Bird {
  RAVEN = 'raven',
  PIGEON = 'pigeon',
}

const creatureList: Array<{
  type: Animal | Bird ;
  name: string;
}> = [
  {
    type: 'cat',
    name: 'Mauricio',
  },
  {
    type: 'raven',
    name: 'Jacob',
  },
]

I need something like that:
function isAnimal(type: Animal | Bird): type is Animal {
  return Object.values(Animal).includes(type);
}

function isBird(type: Animal | Bird): type is Bird {
  return Object.values(Bird).includes(type);
}

creatureList.forEach((creature) => {
  // do something

  if (isAnimal(creature.type)) {
    // do something for animals
  }

  if (isBird(creature.type)) {
    // do something for birds
  }

  // do something else
});

But when I try to do this I get an error:

TS2345: Argument of type 'Animal | Bird' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Animal'.   Type 'Bird.RAVEN' is not assignable to type 'Animal'.

on line
  return Object.values(Animal).includes(type);

How can I correctly check which of the enums a value belongs to?

First, TypeScript enums are opaque or nominal meaning you can't assign a literal string to an enum type even if it's the same value.
const creatureList: Array<{
  type: Animal | Bird;
  name: string;
}> = [
  {
    type: Animal.CAT,
    name: "Mauricio",
  },
  {
    type: Animal.DOG,
    name: "Jacob",
  },
];

Secondly, Object.values() is generic and type safe. Object.values(Animal) returns Animal[]. If you try to check if an array of Animals .includes() a Animal | Bird the compiler will complain since a potential Bird is not assignable to the parameter type of .includes() (which is Animal).
I think it's best to use an explicit generic argument e. g. unkonwn, string or typeof type to widen the return type of Object.values() like so:
function isAnimal(type: Animal | Bird): type is Animal {
  return Object.values<unknown>(Animal).includes(type);
}

function isBird(type: Animal | Bird): type is Bird {
  return Object.values<unknown>(Bird).includes(type);
}

TypeScript Playground

I'm showing the type in creatureList as a string because I got that array from the API, so it's really just a string.
Using "Object.values" helped, thanks.

Your problem is that the type in creatureList isn't your enum type. Enums in typescript behave different from other types. You need to replace the value with the assignment.
const creatureList: Array<{
  type: Animal | Bird ;
  name: string;
}> = [
  {
    type:  Animal.CAT,
    name: 'Mauricio',
  },
  {
    type: Animal.DOG,
    name: 'Jacob',
  },
]

